# Wordpress Menus based on content (posts by categories or somehow pages)

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Not sure if I am missing something very blatant or (much more doubtful) I am asking something that hasn't been asked very much (or in a very easily found place on google)...

I am outlining the process to put  together a site with a bunch of information (in the form of posts or pages, shouldn't matter) organized into categories.

The categories are as such:

- Category: Policies
  Post/Pages under this category: Work Policy, Time off policy, desk policies, etc.
- Category: Forms
  Post/Pages under this category: Benefits Form, Medical Form, Purchase Order Form, etc.
- Benefits
  Post/Pages under this category: Medical, Dental, Optical, etc.

Is there an easy way to have WP create drop down menus as such:

```
Policies
-->Work Policy
-->Time off policy
-->Desk policies

Forms
-->Benefits Form
-->Medical Form
-->Purchase Order Form
```

etc.

Automatically without manually adding each? (also if any posts were added in the future they would automatically appear so long as they were categorized properly).

I am using a the simplex theme , which I have customized myself (http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/simplex)

If I need an additional plugin , etc. that should not be a problem.

Thanks a lot!
-M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that theme - or did you modify it - to use the WP3 menu system wp_nav_menu? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

The WP3 menu can be used to easily add category menu links: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide